# How do I use Promise.all() and an async loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to wrap my head around Promises and how to use them on async loops.

I gathered the following code to read the contents of three files (using `forEach`) and when all promises resolve log the output of all files:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var files = ['1.json','2.json','3.json'];
var promises = []

files.forEach(function(file){
    fs.readFile(path.join('./',file), 'utf8', function(err,data){
        promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            resolve(data)
        })
                );
    })
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(values){
    console.log(values)
});
```

I don't know how to put the loop inside the `.all()`

I tried this code but this logs an empty array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: a) don't use `forEach` (but better `map`) b) you're *`push`ing* the promise asynchronously, the array is empty when `Promise.all` receives it. Construct the promise immediately, and only *`resolve`* it asynchronously

Comment: this article has it, nicely described
https://medium.com/@bluepnume/even-with-async-await-you-probably-still-need-promises-9b259854c161

Answer (score 5):

You're mixing callbacks with promises, create an array of promises using `Array#map` and pass it to `Promise.all`:

```
var files = ['1.json', '2.json', '3.json'];
var promises = files.map(file => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join('./',file), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(values){
    console.log(values)
});
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Another question. How would this code change if the source of the filenames array was on itself the result of an async function?

Comment: In that case, you need to add the function for loading filenames to a promise chain (start promise chain from this function): `getFilesNames().then(fileNames => Promise.all(fileNames.map(...))).then(values => ...)`

Comment: So can I define the function before and then just call it? Also, it should return a promise, correct?

Comment: Yes, the function should be defined before, and should return a promise.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over your array, starting an async call for each, then returning the promise for each call. The return value from that map will be a new array of promises which you can then pass to `Promise.all()`.

```
let Promise = require('bluebird')
let fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'))

let promises = files.map((file) => {
  // readFile will return promises because of bluebird promisifyAll
  return fs.readFile(...)
})

Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
  // results will be an array of all the files that were read
  console.log(results);
});
```